# How To Instantiate a java.util.ArrayList with Generic Class Using Reflection

Tags: java

How To Instantiate a java.util.ArrayList with Generic Class Using Reflection? I am writing a method that sets java.util.List on target object. A target object and a generic type of list is knowing in runtime:

```
public static void initializeList(Object targetObject, PropertyDescriptor prop, String gtype) {
    try {
        Class clazz = Class.forName("java.util.ArrayList<"+gtype+">");
        Object newInstance = clazz.newInstance();
        prop.getWriteMethod().invoke(targetObject, newInstance);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15):

An object doesn't know about its generic type at execution time. Just create a new instance of the raw type (`java.util.ArrayList`). The target object won't know the difference (because there *isn't* any difference).

Basically Java generics is a compile-time trick, with metadata in the compiled classes but just casting at execution time. See the [Java generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html) for more information.

Comment: just for not creating duplicate answers, using reflection is just like doing `new ArrayList<Object>()` because a "generic class" is interpreted as an `Object` at runtime

Answer (score 7):

There's no need to do any reflection for creating your List.  Just pass in some additional type information (usually done by passing a class of the correct type).

```
public static <T> List<T> createListOfType(Class<T> type) {
    return new ArrayList<T>();
}
```

Now you have a list of the required type you can presumably/hopefully set it directly on your `targetObject` without any reflection.

Answer (score 2):

Generics are a compile-time only "trick".

Reflection is runtime-only.

Basically, you can't - you can only create a "raw" `ArrayList`.  If you need to pass it into methods that take generic parameters, casting it directly after construction will be safe (regardless of the "unchecked" warning).  In this example, there's no compile-time type safety anyway due to using general `Objects`, so no casting is needed.

Comment: Generics is not completely a compile-time only thing. Concrete type parameters in field, method and class definitions are actually present in the bytecode and can be acquired at runtime via reflection.

Answer (score 0):

Generics only work at compile time, therefore if you're using reflection, they won't be available.

See more about this [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

Answer (score 0):

An object doesn't know about its generic type at execution time. Just create a new instance of the raw type (java.util.ArrayList). The target object won't know the difference (because there isn't any difference).

Answer (score 0):

Generics is largely a compile time feature.  What you are trying to do is the same as

```
public static void initializeList(Object targetObject, PropertyDescriptor prop, String gtype) {
    prop.getWriteMethod().invoke(targetObject, new ArrayList());
}
```

Note: This could change with Types in Java 7.