# How to define a Generic class that can have type T or type List<T>

Tags: java, generics, jackson

My Java Generics is rusty returning to Java after a long time away.

I am trying to create a generic base class to wrap Jacksons `ObjectMapper`

```
abstract class MyBaseClass<T> {
  private Class<T> clazz;
  public void read() {
       objectMapper.readValue(json, clazz)
  }

  abstract Class<T> getGenericTypeClass();
}
```

The issue I am having is that sometimes T is an instance of a class, and sometimes it needs to be `List<T>`.  My code works for the former, but I can't get it to compile when I have the list scenario.  So this

```
class Sub extends MyBaseClass<Thing> {
    @Override
    getGenericTypeClass() {
       return Thing.class;
    }
}
```

works fine, but when I need `List<Thing>` I'm a bit lost.

Comment: If you need `List<String>`, you might need to consider type tokens (from http://stackoverflow.com/a/75345/2413303 ) - I tinkered with them [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30096160/2413303) but I don't know if it's of any help.

Comment: There is a `Thing.class` but there is not a `List<Thing>.class` only a `List.class`, so the type information of `<Thing>` would be lost. This external library you're using might have some other api to deal with cases like that. It really depends on the library in this case.

Comment: But you can also look at [this article](https://bthurley.wordpress.com/2012/07/18/accessing-generic-type-info-at-runtime/) and Spring's `GenericTypeResolver`

Comment: You need a `TypeReference` for parameterized types with Jackson. But the type has to be known at compile time, ie. not the type variable `T`.

Comment: @JornVernee I updated the question with more info.

Comment: @hvgotcodes Sotirios is right. Jackson's `TypeReference` does have the capability to store the type parameter. You could change the `Class<T>` to `TypeReference<T>`. You would have to pass in the concrete type in a `TypeReference` when instantiating your class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. And you shouldn't. A `Thing` and a `List<Thing>` are totally different. They are analogous to a *Car* and a *Carpark*.

I suggest always returning `List<Thing>`, wrapping a single `Thing` in a singleton List if required.

Here's one (easy) way;

```
public void read() {
   objectMapper.readValue("[" + json.replaceAll("^\\[|]$", "") + "]", clazz);
}
```

Where `clazz` is a `TypeReference` for `List<Thing>`.

The string manipulation guarantees the JSON will be wrapped in `"[...]"`, adding wrapping square brackets if there are none.