# Find out if GSON's TypeToken contains a List?

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm using GSON to parse json in Java. When I want to get an integer list from a json String, my code may look like this:

```
    Type type = new TypeToken<List<Integer>>(){}.getType();

    List<Integer> result = null;
    try {
        result = new Gson().fromJson(jsonStringGoesHere, type);
    } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

If `jsonStringGoesHere` is an empty String or null, `result` is also null.

It is considered bad practice to have an Collection equal null though, so I would prefer to have an empty List instead of null for this case.

So basically this is what I want to do now: If `result` is null, I want to check if `type` is a `List` (or a subtype of `List`). If true, I'll make result an empty ArrayList. How do I check whether `type` contains a `List` or subtype of `List` though?

My attempt was checking `if(type instanceof Collection)` - but that returns false.

My next try was to take `type.getTypeName()` which returns the String `java.util.List<java.lang.Integer>`, and tried to create an object from that:

```
        Class c = Class.forName(type.getTypeName());
        Object o = c.newInstance();
        if(o instanceof List){
            System.out.println("it's working!");
        }
```

But this throws `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.util.List<java.lang.Integer>`.

Any ideas how to make this work?

Comment: change List to ArrayList in `Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Integer>>(){}.getType();`. check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4818228/how-to-instantiate-a-java-util-arraylist-with-generic-class-using-reflection

Comment: @Ibrahim Doing that, `result` still is null, `instanceof` still returns false and creating a newInstance() still throws `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Integer>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My attempt was checking `if(type instanceof Collection)` - but that returns `false`.

This won't work because `Type` and `Collection` are not "mutually castable" and exist in different hierarchies.

> My next try was to take `type.getTypeName()` which returns the String `java.util.List<java.lang.Integer>`

This won't work either. `Class.forName` returns an existing `Class<?>` instance by a fully qualified name (simply speaking, something that's represented by a `.class` file in `CLASSPATH`), but never -- a parameterized class (classes are not parameterizable but can be subclasses with parameterized superclasses -- this is what's under the hood of type tokens). Thus, `Class.forName("java.util.List")` makes sense, but `Class.forName("java.util.List<String>")` does not.

Note that `Type` is *something that can represent a type*, and `TypeToken<T>` serves this purpose. Just take a look at how it's declared -- and you'll understand it better. Even more, its subinterface `ParameterizedType` can hold type parameters, and this this can be generated either by `TypeToken` or constructed manually (as usual -- just take a look at the interface declaration). `TypeToken`s usually use anonymous base class parameterization to take the type parameters from, and that's why they are designed like that: well-done compile-time support + there are similar techniques in Google Guava, Jackson, Spring Framework (but it would be nice if Java could support something like `java.util.List<Integer>.type` to get a parameterized type instance). As of later Gson versions, you can even use `TypeToken.getParameterized(...)` that is simply a convenience method to create a parameterized type.

What you're looking for is, a "class-instanceof" or "a-subclass-of" (if it's fine to call it like that): `Class.isAssignableFrom(...)`. This instance method checks if one class is the same or a subclass of a another class. Say,

```java
SuperClass.class.isAssignableFrom(SubClass.class)
```

always returns `true`. So you only have to check like this:

```java
final Type type = new TypeToken<List<Integer>>() {
}.getType();
final TypeToken<?> typeToken = TypeToken.get(type);
System.out.println(List.class.isAssignableFrom(typeToken.getRawType()));
```

Or even shorter:

```java
final TypeToken<List<Integer>> typeToken = new TypeToken<List<Integer>>() {
};
System.out.println(List.class.isAssignableFrom(typeToken.getRawType()));
```

Both return `true`. Note that type tokens return `Class<?>` instances via `getRawType()`, but not `getType()` since the latter may represent not a class (say, what would `Collection<String>.class.isAssignableFrom(List<Integer.class>)` return?)

Also, you can extract type tokens and its types to `static final` fields since they are meant to be immutable values and should not change in runtime.

Comment: It would be nice and appreciated if you put the output of the code examples.

Answer (score 0):

In Java Generic part of collection comes into play at compile time, and therefore it is not available at runtime and that is the reason you are getting that exception. So if you want to create class of **Collection** type using reflection then you have to remove the generic part.

Also **List**,**Set** and **Map** are interfaces they can not be instantiated directly. So in order to create an object you have to use one of their implementation, like **ArrayList**,**LinkedList** etc.