# Can I use Class in generics?

Tags: java, java-7

If I know the data type for an array list run time, can I use it in generics ?

For example, Can I use Class (say `String.class`) during declaration of an array list below.

```
List objList = new ArrayList<DestinationClassToBeReplaced>();
```

Comment: you can use List<String> list = new ArrayList(); If you ought to use String in list this is the generic way.

Comment: public static <T> List<T> createListOfType(Class<T> type) {
    return new ArrayList<T>();
}

Or u can use a flexible method to use one. refer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4818228/how-to-instantiate-a-java-util-arraylist-with-generic-class-using-reflection)

Comment: What do you think this would accomplish? Sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 2):

```
List<String> objList = new ArrayList<>();
```

is meant for doing that itself and the [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) javadoc clearly states that.

> ```
> Type Parameters:
> E - the type of elements in this list
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You can write like this:

```
List<DestinationClassToBeReplaced> objList = new ArrayList<>();
```

The `<>` operator is called the Diamond operator.

The above code is inferring generic class's instantiation parameter type with JDK 7's `Diamond Operator`

Answer (score 1):

Three ways can be used to declare generic lists

Method 1: use generics i.e.  on both sides

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Method 2: using generic on the left and the diamond operator on the right side

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Method 3: using generic only at left side

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList();
```

Of the above three the second method was introduced in java 7.

If you want to use generics you must specify type on the left for it to work.
Note that the type restriction of generics is thrown away by compiler after checking it during compilation.

Adding generic only on the right will serve you no purpose.